# How do I see what code created a feature?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an updated working copy of some code on a main branch.

There is a new feature within this code.
I want to see the code changes which created that feature.

I have the list of revisions and I can go through them one by one for each file that is effected by the feature - however, the person who coded it was learning on the go.  I want to avoid going through their learning and just see the final result (skipping that person's dead ends and typos).

I would like to get the difference between the current (updated) working copy and the code as it existed before this person started the feature (I know the first revision number used).

Is there a way to do a 'code review' of "net" code changes between a given revision in svn and the code in my working directory?

I use TortoiseSVN, but command line answers are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

[`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) in it's third form

`svn diff -r OLD:NEW` (can't recall TSVN's way)